# Non-Nullable String Initializes as Null

Tags: c#, string, initialization

I trying to understand why a non-nullable string initializes to null instead of an empty string. For example:

```
//Property of class foo
public string Address_Notes { get; set; }

//Create instance of foo
foo myFoo = new foo();

//Get value of Address_Notes
var notesValue = myFoo.Address_Notes; //Returns null
```

Am I crazy to think that a non-nullable string's value should default to `String.Empty`? Is there a standard way of forcing this behavior, other than a custom getter?

Comment: What is a "non-nullable" string?

Comment: @CodingGorilla, you know, after I posted this, I thought to myself - "What's a non-nullable string?". Honestly, I'm not sure what I was thinking. I blame it on writing ColdFusion right before a *real* language...

Comment: actually, if you were using Spec# you're allowed to write signatures like 'void Test(string! s)' which says 's shouldn't be null'. well, that's null-checking rather than non-nullable but still, if that makes it into C# I'd expect a followup of your question :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "non-nullable string".

String is a reference type, so its default value is indeed a null.

You could get around the issue by setting the value to `String.Empty` in the constructor for your class (foo).

Answer (score 11):

A string is a reference type, it's always nullable.

Answer (score 3):

String is reference type - values are initialized to `null` by default.

You can initialize strings in constructor to `string.Empty`, and it is best practice to do it, because:

- `null` value means "I do not know what is the value"
- `string.Empty`
  means "value is empty" or "value does not exists".

So, almost every string properties should be (by you) initialized to `string.Empty` value. Try to read something about "null object pattern". Programming  according this principle makes much more readable and bug-proof code.

Comment: I know this answer is really old, but there are many times when a null initialization is totally appropriate, specifically those where you do not know what the value is.  For example, if you have a data transfer object with a string property, it makes sense for the constructor to initialize it to null, since the person creating that class definition really doesn't want to say "I know this value is empty until you tell me otherwise."  For this reason, I make all of the properties in my DTOs nullable, e.g., `Int32?`.  Why?  I don't know in advance that zero is valid!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using properties to get the string values, another option is to return string.Empty if it is in fact null.

```
//Property of class foo
private string _address_Notes;
public string Address_Notes 
{ 
    get { return _address_Notes ?? string.Empty; } 
    set { _address_Notes = value; }
}
```

---

A much better solution would be to initialise the string to string.Empty (if that is your expected behaviour). You can do this in C# 6+ as follows:

```
public string Address_Notes { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

This way it's a one off initialisation rather than a check on every request.