# Non-nullable property is null

Tags: c#

I have a very simple class `Address`:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I declared `Name` as `string` and *NOT* as `string?`, because it should never be `null`.

Now i have a method where i get an instance of this class as parameter:

```
public List<Address> SearchAddress(Address search)
{
    ...
    if (!search.Name.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        temp = query.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(search.Name));
    }
    ...
}
```

Now my colleague called this method and i got a `System.ArgumentNullException` because `search.Name` is `null`.

If i have a non-nullable `int` property i get `0` as value if i don't assign anythig to it.

Why is a non-nullable `string` property `null` if no value is assigned and not just `string.Empty`?

Comment: `String` is a reference type, the default value is `null`.

Comment: `string` is nullable, `string?` will not get compiled; your test should be `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Name)){...}`

Comment: Reference types can *always* hold `null`. `int` is a value type, and value types behave sufficiently differently that comparing `string` to `int` will only end up confusing you.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. But please tell me what is wrong with this question people are downvoting it so i can edit it. I tried to phrase it really general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Nullable String Initializes as Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822316/non-nullable-string-initializes-as-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a **non-nullable value type** (i.e., a `struct`). Value type fields will be initialized to their default value. E.g., `int` to 0, `bool` to false, etc. Full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

When you want to be able to assign `null` to value type variables, you can use `Nullable<T> where T : struct` or, in the case of an `int`, `Nullable<int>`/`int?`.

`string`, on the other hand, is a **reference type**. Reference types **can** be null, and reference type fields will be initialized as null. As such, having a `Nullable<string>`/`string?` is not allowed nor would it make sense.

In your case, you'll want to check whether the `Name` string is null or empty

```
if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Name)) { ... }
```

Comment: `int?` is also a value type. Saying that value types cannot be null, and then saying that a different value type can be null, is likely to confuse needlessly.

Comment: @hvd Good point. As far as I know, `int?` cannot be *truly* null. All `int? i = null` does is set the `HasValue` property to false. I rephrased "when you want value types to be null" to "when you want to be able to assign null to value type variables". Is that clearer now?

Comment: Well, sort of: `int? i = null; object o = i;` will set `o` to `null`. After that, `i.ToString()` is allowed, but `o.ToString()` is not. But I was focusing more on the "int is a value type ... and cannot be null", which strongly implies that value types can never be null (as you say, sort of true, but you do use `null` for `int?` too), and which I'd rephrase as "int is a non-nullable value type".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't know the difference between this types.

Answer (score 0):

String can hold null values, its simple as that!

String is a reference type, but is has certain behavior of value type.

Please read this topic :  [Null strings and empty strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Nulls)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to determine a instance if it is Null and empty string .

Answer (score 0):

string is a reference type and it's null by default. String.empty is equivalent to a double quoted empty string ("") and hence null is not the same as String.empty.