# How i can say EF6 not insert NULL value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I set deafaultValue in migration

```
AlterColumn("Users", "NotNullValue", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "Work it!"));
```

then i try add new object, and SqlProfiler show me query

```
INSERT [dbo].[WowTable]([NotNullValue],[OnceMoreValue]) VALUES (NULL, 'val')
```

that throw "cannot insert the value null into column"

is that any way to stop inserting and updating property when it null?

UPD:
Domain class:

```
public class User 
{
    public string NotNullValue { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OnceMoreValue { get; set; }        
}
```

Update method:

```
  public Task AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, entity);
        return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

calling:

```
AddOrUpdate(new User{OnceMoreValue = "val"});
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822316/861716). You can't make string not-nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You can either validate the model using [Required] attribute for NotNullValue property:

```
public class User 
{
[Required]
public string NotNullValue { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public string OnceMoreValue { get; set; }        
}
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/gg193959.aspx

Or from what I see in your migration script, you have a default value for this property ("Work It"). So in your User class constructor, you can set NotNullvalue = "Work It" so that this default value will be saved in the case you mentioned:

```
AddOrUpdate(new User{OnceMoreValue = "val"});
```